# Sample size issue

Tags: chi-squared-test, sample-size

I have conducted a questionnaire survey of 20 questions, each question of one answer selection, but only one question is a multiple choice question. The sample size was 1000, means 1000 participants had answered my survey, BUT the sample size increased to 1400 for that particular multiple choice questions; means those 1000 participants select more than one answer within that one multiple choice question, So the sample size for that particular question was 1400. Still the sample size was constant through the rest of the questions. Can I still perform Pearson Chi-square test although the sample size was not constant through the survey? But the number of participants was the same.

Comment: please [edit] your title to be an informative description of what you'd like to know

Comment: What is it you want to test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your multiple choice question isn't a single question, but multiple "Yes/No" questions disguised in a single question. You don't have a sample of 1400 observations, you have a sample of 1000 observations for each individual option in the question.

For instance, consider this question:

> What kind of transportation have you already used in your lifetime?
> Pick all options that apply:
>
> -bike
>
> -car
>
> -bus
>
> -train
>
> -plane

In reality, this question is asking:

> Have you ever traveled by bike? Yes/no
>
> Have you ever traveled by car?
> Yes/no
>
> Have you ever traveled by bus? Yes/no
>
> Have you ever traveled by
> train? Yes/no
>
> Have you ever traveled by plane? Yes/no

-- except that the "Yes/No" options do not appear explicitly in the first version of the question, so that you won't be able to distinguish between someone who completely skipped the question, erroneously omitted to pick a specific option, or refused to answer, and someone who would pick "no" if the question had been asked more explicitly.

Besides this problem, treating these questions as if they were a single question would be incorrect in the context of a chi-square test, as the assumption of independence of observations would be violated (i.e. the same person counted multiple times in the contingency table). You shouldn't conduct a chi-square test on such a table.

Therefore, if you want to conduct chi-square tests, you have to consider that you have as many different variables as there are options in your question.

But even then, a chi-square test may not be the best option you have anyway, depending on what you're looking for exactly. Maybe you should mention that.